# How to set variable name in lowercase on VSTS CI in `.vsts-ci.yml`?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Given the following `.vsts-ci.yml` file:

```
queue: Hosted Linux Preview
variables:
    foo: bar

steps:
- script: |
    ./test.sh
```

And the following `test.sh` file:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo ${foo}
```

I get empty output. However, when I change the file to:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo ${FOO}
```

I get the output `bar`.

Is there a way to disable the conversion of variable names to uppercase so that `.vsts-ci.yml` works with tools that expect variables in lowercase or mixed case names?

Comment: You can use the script `- task: ms-devlabs.utilitytasks.task-Shellpp.Shell++@0
  displayName: 'Shell Script'
  inputs:
    type: FilePath

    scriptPath: test.sh` instead.

Answer (score 1):

This is an expected behavior and there is no way to control this. Refer to this link for details: [Define and modify your variables in a script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/process/variables?view=vsts&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-in-script).

> To define or modify a variable from a script, use the task.setvariable
>   logging command. Note that the updated variable value is scoped to the
>   phase being executed, and does not flow across phases or environments.
>   **Variable names are transformed to uppercase**, and the characters "."
>   and " " are replaced by "_".
>
> For example, Agent.WorkFolder becomes AGENT_WORKFOLDER. On Windows,
>   you access this as %AGENT_WORKFOLDER or $env:AGENT_WORKFOLDER. On
>   Linux and macOS, you use $AGENT_WORKFOLDER.

Comment: I think it's expected behavior if you know the design. It is not expected behavior if you're just a "regular seasoned Unix user". This behavior doesn't make sense. In Unix, environment are case-sensitive and could be lowercase manatory, for example `http_proxy` and `https_proxy`. This is a limitation by design, and for a new pipeline system that's hillarious. Somebody at Microsoft seems to just have transferred some bad DOS design choices from the late 70ies to a DevOps pipeline in the 2010s. (Not complaining about your answer, but the reason why you had to give that response.)

Comment: The reference on Windows should probably be `%AGENT_WORKFOLDER%`, and on Unix it should better be `${AGENT_WORKFOLDER}` to protect inexperienced users from garbled variable names when the variable reference is part of text. Also, on Unix resp. "on Linux and macOS" is actually a wrong statement, as it is not the OS but the shell which determines the syntax for variable replacements, so it should rather be "On `sh`, `bash` and similar typical shells` instead.